# How can I explode an array in eloquent?

Tags: eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a register in the database that contains an array but I can't make relationship with another table on Eloquent, the data is showing like `"act_secundaria" => "70101,74218"`, the relationship is structurated: `public function infoMstCiiuActSec(){
        return $this->hasMany('Models\Maestras\Ciiu', 'codciiu', 'act_secundaria');
    }`

I need to run all the elements in the array. Can you help me, please?